# are alignment of star systems' orbital planes with ours better than random?

Tags: orbital-motion, exoplanets

It obviously helps our observation of exoplanets if they transit their star from our point-of-view. I would guess that the chances of this alignment are better than if their orbital plane was randomly oriented. Gravitational interaction between stars, planets, and the galaxy would increase the likelihood of inter-system alignment just as moons in our system orbit their planets in general alignment of the planets orbit around the Sun. Is this the case? On the other hand, moons in our system generally formed at the same time as the planets, which would not be the case for star systems.

Comment: http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/about-us/159-our-solar-system/the-sun/the-solar-system/236-are-the-planes-of-solar-systems-aligned-with-the-plane-of-the-galaxy-intermediate

Comment: So the short answer is "no" because planetary systems are quite far apart relative to their size. Makes sense. Thanks. Perhaps it is also the long answer. ;-) Is there any influence at all? Does the angle between the orbital plane of a planetary system and its galaxy change during its lifetime? Perhaps we don't have enough data to show this but computer models would presumably provide an answer.

Comment: I do not know that much, I do not work on that area, but I do not think there is any mechanism that could cause that change (but again there might be, let's hope some expert can answer it)